# Name of phenomenon present when creating words such as "patiblanco" or "panzaburro"

Tags: gramática, solicitud-de-término, compuestos

I have seen some words that seem to be made up of two words concatenated, for example:

- "patiblanco" (patas + blanco)
- "panzaburro" (panza + (de) + burro)

Is there a name for this phenomenon in Spanish?

Comment: Our tagging system seems to call them "compuestos."  (I personally call them Scotch-tape words.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se llama [*composición*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composici%C3%B3n_(ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica)):

> En lingüística, la composición es un procedimiento morfológico de las lenguas para crear neologismos, esto es, nuevas palabras. Consiste en coordinar dos o más lexemas o raíces, esto es, partes invariables de palabras, para formar una nueva que constituye una unidad semántica y sintáctica.
>
> ...
>
> - **Verbo + sustantivo:** sacacorchos, abrelatas, aguafiestas.
> - **Sustantivo + adjetivo:** aguamarina, camposanto, pasodoble, pelirrojo, boquiabierto, carilleno.
> - **Adjetivo + sustantivo:** extremaunción. medianoche, salvoconducto, bajorrelieve.
> - **Sustantivo + sustantivo:** bocacalle, coliflor, sueldo base, casa cuna, motocarro, hombre lobo, hispanohablante.
> - **Adjetivo + adjetivo:** sordomudo, verdiazul, agridulce, altibajo.
> - **Adverbio + adjetivo:** biempensante.
> - **Sustantivo + verbo:** fazferir.
> - **Pronombre + verbo:** cualquiera, quehacer, quienquiera.
> - **verbo + verbo:** duermevela.